# Apply SQL Standards to script

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have the following script and would like to change it so that it agrees with the international standards. I use SQL-Server but whenever possible I'd like to follow the international standards for SQL. I don't believe that the square brackets are standard - should I replace them with double quotes?

Without paying to get a copy of the standards document are there any resources on the internet which give examples of scripts formatted and laid out exactly as required by the standards?

```
SELECT 
    a.UserAccountKey,
    SUM(ISNULL(b.[measure Y],0.0)) AS "measure Y",
    SUM(ISNULL(c.[measure Z],0.0)) AS "measure Z"
FROM 
    XXX a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YYYY b ON
        a.UserAccountKey = b.UserAccountKey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ZZZZ c ON
        a.UserAccountKey = c.UserAccountKey
GROUP BY
    a.UserAccountKey
```

---

**EDIT**

My only slight preference that is not classic standard is the following. This was put forward by AaronBertrand and I agree that it's more readable - especially if the `SELECT` clause has 20 or 30 fields:

```
SELECT 
    a.UserAccountKey,
    "measure Y"             = SUM(ISNULL(b."measure Y",0.0)),
    "measure Z"             = SUM(ISNULL(c."measure Z",0.0)),
    "measure longertitle"   = SUM(ISNULL(c."measure longertitle",0.0)),
    "me short"              = SUM(ISNULL(c."me short",0.0))
FROM
```

Comment: In practice, you could use sqlfiddle.com and see if your query (or small subset of it) runs without complains on all databases that sqlfiddle.com supports: MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, SQLite

Comment: +1 for caring about standards

Comment: upped your comment (....you started me caring about the standards)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `ISNULL` to `COALESCE` and square brackets to `"` and then [it validates](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser).

```
SELECT a.UserAccountKey,
       SUM(COALESCE(b."measure Y", 0.0)) AS "measure Y",
       SUM(COALESCE(c."measure Z", 0.0)) AS "measure Z"
FROM   XXX a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN YYYY b
         ON a.UserAccountKey = b.UserAccountKey
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ZZZZ c
         ON a.UserAccountKey = c.UserAccountKey
GROUP  BY a.UserAccountKey;
```

This does mean that you need to ensure that [`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) is `ON` in SQL Server.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation and references - shame the mimer doesn't actually give me corrected code rather than just where the errors are located.

Comment: in terms of formatting, apart from my fingers, are there some tools which can quickly standardize the formatting of my scripts?

Comment: @whytheq - There are no international standards for formatting, only syntax. There are various commercial prettifiers. Such as SQL Pretty Printer or Redgate SQL Prompt.

Comment: Martin - I assume if there are no gaps in the field name then it's ok to just use `b.measureY` rather than `b."measureY"` ?

Comment: @whytheq - Yes `<delimited identifier>` is not required in that case. Search for `<regular identifier>` here for the [SQL 92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) rules

Comment: martin - currently that document is too technical for me - I will keep nipping back to it from time-to-time and I'm sure it will start to make sense. For example on what page does it mention using `"` for `<regular identifier>` ?

Comment: @whytheq - You don't use `"` for `<regular identifier>` that is used to delimit `<delimited identifier>`. You can just run it through the Mimer Validator. It fails [entry level 92](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml) as the identifiers need to be all upper case but validates against intermediate level 92 (and validates against core SQL 2003)

Comment: martin - this seems easier for me to understand [PDF OF 1999](http://dbis-informatik.uibk.ac.at/files/ext/lehre/ss11/vo-ndbm/lit/ORel-SQL1999-IBM-Nelson-Mattos.pdf)

Comment: @whytheq - Thanks for the link. Looks like that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

A good online free T-SQL formatter is http://www.tsqltidy.com/, i.e. for SQL Server. Careful as your firewall admin might suddenly be alerted about an SQL Injection attack (some firewalls mistake using the site for an attack). Otherwise there are commercial tools that have formatting capabilities - SQL Complete (DevArt) and SQL Prompt (Red Gate).

As for "International Standard SQL", that would be more of a blog-site of it's own. Which ANSI Standard (1992, SQL3, ...) and to what level ?

Can help you with the quotes though, use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; before your SQL, and then turn off afterwards (SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;). That means you don't need to switch it on for the whole database. But, it's a good idea NOT use identifiers with spaces and non-standard characters (just as C# with code like "... new Object type I just made up ~() ... " - would not be very practical).

Does that count as 2 answers and another question ?

Comment: +1 thanks for the info - I'll spend a little time checking out sqltidy

Comment: ...I've added an edit of the OP that shows why tsqltidy probably won't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good list of resources for SQL standards with different documents and everything: 
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/language/sql/ansi

If you’re looking for a t-SQL formatter for your existing code you can also check out [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx) . 
It’s a free SSMS plugin similar to SQL Promt from Red Gate.

Answer (score 0):

Another great resource is SQL Cop, which is a free tool that identifies issues and suggests best practices:

http://sqlcop.lessthandot.com/